# Derivative of a Matrix w.r.t. a Matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix product with $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ as $\mathbf{F(X)} = \mathbf{XAA}^T$ where $\mathbf{A}$ is a constant matrix w.r.t. $\mathbf{X}$. I see that I can write the following [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Identities_in_differential_form).
$$
d\mathbf{F(X)} = (d\mathbf{X})\mathbf{AA}^T + \mathbf{X}d(\mathbf{AA}^T) = (d\mathbf{X})\mathbf{AA}^T
$$

From here, can I write,
$$
\frac{d\mathbf{F(X)}}{d\mathbf{X}} = \mathbf{I}_{m\times n}\mathbf{AA}^T = \mathbf{AA}^T
$$

Note that I have taken the help of the fact that the derivative of an ${m\times n}$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$ with respect to itself is $\mathbf{I}_{m\times n}$, as found in page 4 of the [Notes on Matrix Calculus by Paul L. Fackler](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~pfackler/MatCalc.pdf). I'm not sure what exactly $\mathbf{I}_{m\times n}$ is, but I'm taking it as some sort of generalized identity matrix and assuming that premultiplying $\mathbf{AA}^T$ with $\mathbf{I}_{m\times n}$ results in $\mathbf{AA}^T$ only.

So, in short, my question is can I write $\frac{d\mathbf{F(X)}}{d\mathbf{X}}$ as $\mathbf{AA}^T$, in this case?

Comment: Sure - I might it out more completely though as (hopefully not mistaken myself) $\frac{DF(X)}{DX} \cdot H = H \cdot AA^{T}$ (the derivative is a linear map, so you need to know how it acts on a tangent vector and the formula above leaves it a little ambiguous, esp. since the multiplication would be on the right here rather than on the left like usual, though the dimensions suggest the correct side).  Note that the original map $F$ is linear itself so it's (essentially) its own derivative.

Comment: @amomin : I did not, completely, get what $\mathbf{H}$ is. Is it another matrix? In that case, is it such that $\frac{d\mathbf{F(X)}}{d\mathbf{X}} = \mathbf{AA}^T$ only if $\frac{d\mathbf{F(X)}}{d\mathbf{X}}$ comes with another matrix $\mathbf{H}$? In that case, if I take $\mathbf{H} = \mathbf{I}$ then, your expression gives me $\frac{d\mathbf{F(X)}}{d\mathbf{X}}=\mathbf{AA}^T$. Am I right in my thinking? Also a short question - is there any special reason to use upper case $\mathbf{D}$ instead of lower case $d$ for the derivative operator? Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: $H$ would indeed be another matrix.  Expressed another way, for a general differentiable function, we have $f(x+h) \approx f(x) + \frac{df(x)}{dx} (h)$ to first order, so H is another matrix (same dimensions as X).  In your example, $F(X+H) = (X+H)AA^{T} = XAA^{T} + HAA^{T} = F(X) + \frac{dF(X)}{dX}(H)$ (on the nose because $F$ is actually linear).  And I'm totally mixing up the use of D and d here - -I'll correct that in my previous comment- sorry, I don't think I can correct it, but yes replace "D" with "d" in my comment above.

Comment: @amomin : The last explanation made it more clear. I think I did not get one comment fully. Why did you tell - "on the nose because F is actually linear"? Has it something to do with $\frac{dF(\mathbf{X})}{d\mathbf{X}}$ sitting on left of $\mathbf{H}$? And no worries for $d$ vs $D$. The idea is clear. I was making it unnecessarily complicated. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Sorry - I just meant that the $\approx$ is actually an exact $=$ because the function is linear.  When the function is non-linear $\approx$ means "equal to first-order".

Answer (score 4):

The differential is correct
$$\eqalign{
  dF &= dX\,AA^T \cr
   &= I\,dX\,AA^T\cr
}$$
What I normally do at this point is to follow the Magnus-Neudecker convention and apply vec() to both sides
$$\eqalign{
  {\rm vec}(dF) &= (AA^T\otimes I)\,{\rm vec}(dX) \cr
  d{\rm vec}(F) &= (AA^T\otimes I)\,\,d{\rm vec}(X) \cr\cr
  \frac {\partial\,{\rm vec}(F)} {\partial\,{\rm vec}(X)^T} &= AA^T\otimes I \cr
}$$
If you don't use vectorization, then you have to deal with $\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}$ as a full-blown fourth-order tensor.  In which case index notation is the best way to proceed.

In any case, the derivative is definitely not $AA^T$, which is just a matrix, i.e. a second-order tensor.

Comment: "In which case index notation is the best way to proceed" Do you have a reference for where this kind of index notation is developed (and that doesn't rely on differential geometry)?

Answer (score 0):

Derivative (or linearization) of an already linear function is the function itself. Indeed following the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Definition) let us keep the h-linear term in
$$
f(x+h)-f(x)=f(x)+f(h)-f(x)=f(h)
$$
Hence we write $$D_xf= f$$
In your case, $D_XF=AA^T$ evaluated on any $H\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ as $D_XF(H)=HAA^T.$